# why i got error inspite of that correctly set value to entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Hello my website is made by symfony and mysql.
Now im stuck in this error.

> publisher_id cannot be null.

this errror means that `publisher_id` column of volume table can not be null.
this error is correct but i set value to `publisher_id` 
and i did `var_dump` like below and i got correct Entity.

```php
$volume = new Volume(); //instanciate Volume Entity.
$volume->setISBN($ISBN);
$volume->setStorePublisher($publisher); //set Publisher Entity to Volume Entity.

var_dump($publisher->getId()); //correct id shown.why no publisher id???

$volume->setCreatedAt(Context::now());
$volume->setUpdatedAt(Context::now());

$em = Context::getEntityManagerWrite();
$em->transactional(function (EntityManager $em) use (&$volume) {
    $volume = $em->merge($volume); // i got error here.why ??
    $em->flush();
    //....
}
```

Comment: I add a `}` when I edited you code can you confirm that I placed it right and that the `flush()` is inside the transactional ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Your Error:

To begin with your problem you're trying to merge an unmanaged Entity,
Persist it inside the `em` first as such :

```php
$volume = new Volume();
$volume->setISBN($ISBN);
$volume->setStorePublisher($publisher); 
$volume->setCreatedAt(Context::now());
$volume->setUpdatedAt(Context::now());

$em->persist($volume);

// do stuff
```

#### FYI:

in you entity add the `__construct` method to remove this ugly `createAt()`from your controller

```
class Volume {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCreateAt(new \DateTime());
    }
}
```

For the `updateAt()` you can use services as shown in the [Doc](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html). The objective is to keep your `Controller`as light as possible.

Comment: im begginer with doctrine. really really thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! As I'm a beginner with SO, don't hesitate to upvote and mark my answer as solution.